# Eclipse Preference - Customized

Tags: java, eclipse, preferences

How can I create a customized preference page with tree structured view.
Only on selection of CP Value Range, I need to open preference page.

[image]

Currently it's showing for root node.

[image]

My extension is like this:

```
    <extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages">
   <page
         class="com.bosch.sharcc.uct.rcp.branding.preferences.ALCControllerCPRangePreferencePage"
         id="com.abc.efg.branding.controllerpreferencepage"
         name="Controller">
   </page>
   <page
         category="com.abc.efg.branding.controllerpreferencepage"
         id="com.abc.efg.branding.alcpreferencepage"
           class="com.abc.efg.branding.preferences.ALCControllerCPRangePreferencePage"
         name="ALC">
   </page>
   <page
         category="com.abc.efg.branding.alcpreferencepage"
         class="com.abc.efg.branding.preferences.ALCControllerCPRangePreferencePage"
         id="com.abc.efg.branding.cprangepreferencepage"
         name="CP Value Range">
   </page>
</extension>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this. Testing here it works as expected.

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_launch_the_preference_page_that_belongs_to_my_plug-in%3F